# Proving the number of permutations about a fixed point

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,2,\cdots,n\},i\in S$ is said to be a fixed point of a permutation $p$ of $S$ if $p(i)=i$ Let $p_n(k)$ be the number of permutations of $S$ which have $k$ fixed points. Prove $$\sum_{k=0}^n k.p_n(k)=n!$$

Could someone just explain what this question means??I could not understand anything. I know that this question is a repeat but the answers posted for that question were too above my standard.(I am in class 10) Please help.

Please check my try with $n=3$:-

$k=0$ then no. of fixed points$=0$ So $p(0)=3!$ but $0.p(0)=0$

$k=1$ then no. of fixed points$=1$ So $p(1)=2!=2$ So $1.p(1)=2$

$k=2$ then no. of fixed points$=2$ So $p(2)=1!=1$ So $2.p(2)=2$

$k=3$ then no. of fixed points$=3$ So $p(3)=1!=1$ So $3.p(3)=3$

$$\sum_{k=0}^3 k.p_3(k)=0+2+2+3=7$$ But my answer is not $3!$
Where am I wrong??

Comment: I think it should say $\sum_{k=0}^n p_n(k)=n!$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Could you please explain what the question means?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, the statement is correct.

Comment: Why don't you try the case n=3 as an example?  There are only 6 permutations, so you easily count the number of fixed points "by hand".